# Create a class that contains the NumPy array that also can print the NumPy values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, class, printing

```
import sys
import numpy 

my_file = open("/Users/Daniel/Desktop/attached.txt", "r")
content_list = my_file.readlines()

print(content_list)

arr = numpy.array(content_list)
print ("Array: ", arr)
```

I am trying to get create a class that contains this NumPy array and can print the NumPy values, I am not sure how to start. Any help would be appreciated.
**more explanation:** I would like to make a class first, that includes my NumPy array that I made earlier. This class should be able to print the values of the NumPy array that I created.

Comment: Okay, but what problem are you having? Just not sure how to create a class?

Comment: Yes, not exactly sure how to make a class that contains a numpy array

Comment: The question is not clear. please add more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
import sys
import numpy 

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, filepath):
        my_file = open(filepath, "r")
        content_list = my_file.readlines()
        self.arr = numpy.array(content_list)

    def print_values(self):
        print(self.arr)

c = MyClass("/Users/Daniel/Desktop/attached.txt")
c.print_values()
```

You should look at some documentation about [Python classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html). There are a lot of examples of object oriented programming and just how to use Python in general.

Answer (score 0):

Try out loading txt file through NumPy such that it loads as array but it always depends on the *dtype* inside your file. Here I'm attaching some examples:

**Syntax**:

```
numpy.loadtxt(fname, dtype = float, comments=’#’, delimiter=None,
                        converters=None, skiprows=0, usecols=None, unpack=False,
                        ndmin=0, encoding=’bytes’, max_rows=None, *, like= None)
```

```
import numpy as np
# Text file data converted to integer data type
File_data = np.loadtxt("example1.txt", dtype=int)
print(File_data)
```

Change the *dtype* depending on what you have in the file, But for complete reference of what you can do you can refer here from the
[NumPy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should be more specific about what are you intending to do but here is what I understood.

```
import numpy

class ArrayPrinter:

    def __init__(self, numpy_array):
        self.numpy_array = numpy_array

    def print_my_array(self):
        for i in self.numpy_array:
            print(i)


"""create the numpy array"""
arr = numpy.arange(4)

"""create the printer object"""
my_array_printer = ArrayPrinter(arr)
"""use object method"""
my_array_printer.print_my_array()
```